Regression with highly unbalanced explanatory variable - Continuation from my previous post
This is a continuation from my previous post available in Regression with highly unbalanced explanatory variable
The accepted answer states that the impact of having unbalanced explanatory categorical variable is inflated estimates of SE of the corresponding model coefficient.
However, this brings me towards a followup question, as such unbalanced nature in explanatory variable in the sample used to estimate model coefficients can occure in mainly two different ways 1) in the population itself there is such unbalanced nature in the explanatory variable and/or 2) the design of sample may not be accurate or it is just  a chance that in the sample one category has very less number of observations whereas other category has got large number of sample values.
So my question is would the impact of unbalanced explanatory categorical variable be same on the estimated model for both cases?
